# Why do I get 2 of the same maps rendered?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I want to show map in my React application. Here's codes:

```
export const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const view = new MapView(
      {
          map: new Map({ basemap: "arcgis-community"}),
          container: "map",
          center: [137.8239,36.2068],
          zoom: 5,
      }
    );
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id='map'></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I got:

[image]

Looking at the dev console:

[image]

I assume it is the `MapView` that creates 2 maps: `esri-view-root` and `esri-view-root-storage`. What's the reason for this behavior?

Comment: That looks ok to me, I think your problem is that you are not importing the arcgis js main css. Can you check that?.

Comment: You are right, I'm an idiot :| Thanks!

Comment: Glad you solve it!